# Why can't I access the JSon data?

Tags: php, ajax, json

I'm trying to get the count of a variable using ajax but it keeps printing fail everytime

here is the php file that works perfectly when I test it

```
 <?php 

$conn= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect to mysql"); 

mysqli_select_db($conn,"bdpfe") or die ("no database");   
$rech=$_GET['q'];


$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select count(id_com) as nbr from commentaire where  id_pub like '".$rech."' "); 

$response = array();
$nbrs = array();
$result=$sql;

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
$nbr=$row['nbr'];

$nbrs[] = array('nbr'=>$nbr);
 } 

 $response['nbrs'] = $nbrs;

 echo "mycallbackcom(".json_encode($response).")";

 ?>
```

and here is the ajax call using jsonp

```
 (function  getnbr() {
$.ajax({
type : 'GET', 
url : 'http://127.0.0.1:800/test/count_com.php?callback=?&q='+$('#idpub').val() , 
jsonpCallback: 'mycallbackcom',
dataType: 'jsonp',
contentType: "application/json",
success: function (data) {
 alert("succes");
},
error: function () {

   alert("fail");
       }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

and the callback function is empty for now:

```
function mycallbackcom()
{}
```

it keeps printing fail every time.

Answer (score 3):

Try only returning the JSON. You have specified this as your expected return dataType.

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

Then handle the response:

```
 (function getnbr() {
     $.ajax({
        type : 'GET', 
        url : 'http://127.0.0.1:800/test/count_com.php?callback=?&q='+$('#idpub').val() , 
        jsonpCallback: 'mycallbackcom',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            mycallbackcom(data)
         },
         error: function () {
           alert("fail");    
         }    
  });   
});
```

Comment: thats using nrml json and in my case im usin jsonp where the response i s a function and the problem is not in the php im sure it works fine

Comment: Why not just perform that function upon success, and pass in your json? See updated answer.

Comment: i need to be using jsonp as returning the reslut in a function i am obliged to work that way (with jsonp) not by choice

Comment: thanx for the help but it didnt work althought the call to the fucntion is executed if i implment the mycallbackcom function like this

       function mycallbackcom()
       {alert("hi");}

it will print both fail and hi

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the $_GET variable..

```
$data = json_decode($_GET['q']);

function mycallback($data) {
    //Do something
}

return mycallback($data);
```

Comment: sorry i didnt understand how should i try your suggestion